# Python 3.4: List to Dictionary

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a string as follows :

```
['Total Revenue', 31821000, 30871000, 29904000, 'Cost of Revenue', 16447000, 16106000, 15685000, 'Gross Profit', 15374000, 14765000, 14219000, 'Research Development', 1770000, 1715000, 1634000, 'Selling General and Administrative', 6469000, 6384000, 6102000, 'Non Recurring', '-', '-', '-', 'Others', '-', '-', '-', 'Total Operating Expenses', '-', '-', '-', 'Operating Income or Loss', 7135000, 6666000, 6483000, 'Total Other Income/Expenses Net', 33000, 41000, 39000, 'Earnings Before Interest And Taxes', 7168000, 6707000, 6522000, 'Interest Expense', 142000, 145000, 171000, 'Income Before Tax', 7026000, 6562000, 6351000, 'Income Tax Expense', 2028000, 1841000, 1840000, 'Minority Interest', -42000, -62000, -67000, 'Net Income From Continuing Ops', 4956000, 4659000, 4444000, 'Discontinued Operations', '-', '-', '-', 'Extraordinary Items', '-', '-', '-', 'Effect Of Accounting Changes', '-', '-', '-', 'Other Items', '-', '-', '-', 'Net Income', 4956000, 4659000, 4444000, 'Preferred Stock And Other Adjustments', '-', '-', '-', 'Net Income Applicable To Common Shares', 4956000, 4659000, 4444000]
```

there is a pattern that is 1 : 3 within the list.  Is there anyway I can transform this list into a dictionary as exemplified below.

```
{Total Revenue : [31821000, 30871000, 29904000], Cost of Revenue : [16447000, 16106000, 15685000] ... ... ... }
```

I think it can be done through a dictionary comprehension.

Comment: Have you tried using a dictionary comprehension? Can you include code from your attempt(s)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use unpacking operation within a dict comprehension :

```
>>> my_dict={i:j for i,*j in [l[i:i+4] for i in range(0,len(l),4)]}
>>> my_dict
{'Non Recurring': ['-', '-', '-'], 'Total Other Income/Expenses Net': [33000, 41000, 39000], 'Selling General and Administrative': [6469000, 6384000, 6102000], 'Net Income From Continuing Ops': [4956000, 4659000, 4444000], 'Effect Of Accounting Changes': ['-', '-', '-'], 'Net Income Applicable To Common Shares': [4956000, 4659000, 4444000], 'Net Income': [4956000, 4659000, 4444000], 'Other Items': ['-', '-', '-'], 'Others': ['-', '-', '-'], 'Earnings Before Interest And Taxes': [7168000, 6707000, 6522000], 'Income Before Tax': [7026000, 6562000, 6351000], 'Extraordinary Items': ['-', '-', '-'], 'Total Operating Expenses': ['-', '-', '-'], 'Interest Expense': [142000, 145000, 171000], 'Preferred Stock And Other Adjustments': ['-', '-', '-'], 'Gross Profit': [15374000, 14765000, 14219000], 'Total Revenue': [31821000, 30871000, 29904000], 'Income Tax Expense': [2028000, 1841000, 1840000], 'Operating Income or Loss': [7135000, 6666000, 6483000], 'Cost of Revenue': [16447000, 16106000, 15685000], 'Minority Interest': [-42000, -62000, -67000], 'Research Development': [1770000, 1715000, 1634000], 'Discontinued Operations': ['-', '-', '-']}
```

And if you want to preserve the order you can use `collections.OrderedDict` :

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> my_dict=OrderedDict((i,j) for i,*j in [l[i:i+4] for i in range(0,len(l),4)])
>>> my_dict
OrderedDict([('Total Revenue', [31821000, 30871000, 29904000]), ('Cost of Revenue', [16447000, 16106000, 15685000]), ('Gross Profit', [15374000, 14765000, 14219000]), ('Research Development', [1770000, 1715000, 1634000]), ('Selling General and Administrative', [6469000, 6384000, 6102000]), ('Non Recurring', ['-', '-', '-']), ('Others', ['-', '-', '-']), ('Total Operating Expenses', ['-', '-', '-']), ('Operating Income or Loss', [7135000, 6666000, 6483000]), ('Total Other Income/Expenses Net', [33000, 41000, 39000]), ('Earnings Before Interest And Taxes', [7168000, 6707000, 6522000]), ('Interest Expense', [142000, 145000, 171000]), ('Income Before Tax', [7026000, 6562000, 6351000]), ('Income Tax Expense', [2028000, 1841000, 1840000]), ('Minority Interest', [-42000, -62000, -67000]), ('Net Income From Continuing Ops', [4956000, 4659000, 4444000]), ('Discontinued Operations', ['-', '-', '-']), ('Extraordinary Items', ['-', '-', '-']), ('Effect Of Accounting Changes', ['-', '-', '-']), ('Other Items', ['-', '-', '-']), ('Net Income', [4956000, 4659000, 4444000]), ('Preferred Stock And Other Adjustments', ['-', '-', '-']), ('Net Income Applicable To Common Shares', [4956000, 4659000, 4444000])])
```

Also as a more pythonic and efficient way for grouping your list you can use following grouper function from python *[itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes)*

```
>>> def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
...     "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
...     # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
...     args = [iter(iterable)] * n
...     return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
... 
>>> 
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> my_dict=OrderedDict((i,j) for i,*j in grouper(l,4))
>>> my_dict
OrderedDict([('Total Revenue', [31821000, 30871000, 29904000]), ('Cost of Revenue', [16447000, 16106000, 15685000]), ('Gross Profit', [15374000, 14765000, 14219000]), ('Research Development', [1770000, 1715000, 1634000]), ('Selling General and Administrative', [6469000, 6384000, 6102000]), ('Non Recurring', ['-', '-', '-']), ('Others', ['-', '-', '-']), ('Total Operating Expenses', ['-', '-', '-']), ('Operating Income or Loss', [7135000, 6666000, 6483000]), ('Total Other Income/Expenses Net', [33000, 41000, 39000]), ('Earnings Before Interest And Taxes', [7168000, 6707000, 6522000]), ('Interest Expense', [142000, 145000, 171000]), ('Income Before Tax', [7026000, 6562000, 6351000]), ('Income Tax Expense', [2028000, 1841000, 1840000]), ('Minority Interest', [-42000, -62000, -67000]), ('Net Income From Continuing Ops', [4956000, 4659000, 4444000]), ('Discontinued Operations', ['-', '-', '-']), ('Extraordinary Items', ['-', '-', '-']), ('Effect Of Accounting Changes', ['-', '-', '-']), ('Other Items', ['-', '-', '-']), ('Net Income', [4956000, 4659000, 4444000]), ('Preferred Stock And Other Adjustments', ['-', '-', '-']), ('Net Income Applicable To Common Shares', [4956000, 4659000, 4444000])])
```

Answer (score 2):

I would make a helper function that takes your data and generates it in chunks, along with a key:

```
def generate_revenues(data):
    data = iter(data)
    while True:
        key = next(data)
        values = [next(data), next(data), next(data)]
        yield key, values
```

Making the dictionary is then as simple as:

```
>>> dict(generate_revenues(data))
```

which gives:

```
{'Cost of Revenue': [16447000, 16106000, 15685000],
 'Discontinued Operations': ['-', '-', '-'],
 'Earnings Before Interest And Taxes': [7168000, 6707000, 6522000],
 ...
 'Total Operating Expenses': ['-', '-', '-'],
 'Total Other Income/Expenses Net': [33000, 41000, 39000],
 'Total Revenue': [31821000, 30871000, 29904000]}
```

*Technical note for people from the future*: The generator raises a `StopIteration` exception in order to stop iterating. In a future version of Python this will be disallowed, and you'll need to guard the calls to `next` with a `try: except StopIteration:` block.

Answer (score 1):

indeed it can:

```
assert len(lst) % 4 == 0
{lst[4*i]: lst[4*i+1:4*(i+1)] for i in range(len(lst)/4)}
```

Comment: This answer is simply wrong. `for i in len(lst)/4` will tell you an int (in Python 2) or float (Python 3) object is not iterable. If not corrected I'd vote to close. Even with that fixed it's still inconprehensible due to all the arithmetic with the indices, so even when it doesn't error it's not a great answer.

Comment: He meant to use `range(len(lst)/4)` obviously.  Ugly though. ;-)